# Запрос на удаление JDBC prepareStatement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Подскажите в чём проблема.

Нужно сделать массовое удаление из таблицы.

Вот мой запрос:

```
DELETE FROM `doctor_1_4` WHERE `date` = '2016-12-1' AND `time` = '10:10:00';
DELETE FROM `doctor_1_4` WHERE `date` = '2016-12-1' AND `time` = '10:20:00';
DELETE FROM `doctor_1_4` WHERE `date` = '2016-12-1' AND `time` = '10:30:00';
DELETE FROM `doctor_1_4` WHERE `date` = '2016-12-1' AND `time` = '10:40:00';
DELETE FROM `doctor_1_4` WHERE `date` = '2016-12-1' AND `time` = '10:50:00';
DELETE FROM `doctor_1_4` WHERE `date` = '2016-12-1' AND `time` = '11:10:00';
DELETE FROM `doctor_1_4` WHERE `date` = '2016-12-1' AND `time` = '11:20:00';
DELETE FROM `doctor_1_4` WHERE `date` = '2016-12-1' AND `time` = '11:30:00';
DELETE FROM `doctor_1_4` WHERE `date` = '2016-12-1' AND `time` = '11:40:00';
DELETE FROM `doctor_1_4` WHERE `date` = '2016-12-1' AND `time` = '11:50:00';
DELETE FROM `doctor_1_4` WHERE `date` = '2016-12-1' AND `time` = '12:10:00';
DELETE FROM `doctor_1_4` WHERE `date` = '2016-12-1' AND `time` = '12:20:00';
DELETE FROM `doctor_1_4` WHERE `date` = '2016-12-1' AND `time` = '12:30:00';
DELETE FROM `doctor_1_4` WHERE `date` = '2016-12-1' AND `time` = '12:40:00';
DELETE FROM `doctor_1_4` WHERE `date` = '2016-12-1' AND `time` = '12:50:00';
DELETE FROM `doctor_1_4` WHERE `date` = '2016-12-1' AND `time` = '13:10:00';
DELETE FROM `doctor_1_4` WHERE `date` = '2016-12-1' AND `time` = '13:20:00';
DELETE FROM `doctor_1_4` WHERE `date` = '2016-12-1' AND `time` = '13:30:00';
DELETE FROM `doctor_1_4` WHERE `date` = '2016-12-1' AND `time` = '13:40:00';
DELETE FROM `doctor_1_4` WHERE `date` = '2016-12-1' AND `time` = '13:50:00';
DELETE FROM `doctor_1_4` WHERE `date` = '2016-12-1' AND `time` = '14:10:00';
DELETE FROM `doctor_1_4` WHERE `date` = '2016-12-1' AND `time` = '14:20:00';
DELETE FROM `doctor_1_4` WHERE `date` = '2016-12-1' AND `time` = '14:30:00';
DELETE FROM `doctor_1_4` WHERE `date` = '2016-12-1' AND `time` = '14:40:00';
DELETE FROM `doctor_1_4` WHERE `date` = '2016-12-1' AND `time` = '14:50:00';
DELETE FROM `doctor_1_4` WHERE `date` = '2016-12-1' AND `time` = '15:10:00';
```

Запрос я генерирую кодом. Тобишь подставляю в поля, после `=`, данные кодом.

При запросе вылетает `Exeption`:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version 
for the right syntax to use near 
'DELETE FROM `doctor_1_4` WHERE `date` = '2016-12-1' AND `time` = '10:20:00';DELE' at line 1
```

Самое интересное что в phpMyAdmin данный запрос работает без ошибок. а тут нет. в чём проблема может быть? из ошибки я не пойму в чём там дело. всё пересмотрел уже.

Comment: ну как мне кажется, это потому что вы все суете в один запрос!!!! разделите ваши `DELETE` по разным запросам и выполните их. И Ваши `where` изменяются только значения поля `time` почему бы вам не сформировать один большой `where` и потом его подставить в запрос и выполнить?

Comment: @Виктор почему тогда в phpMyAdmin всё работает?

Comment: Потому что там обработчик запроса заточен только под запросы и там простыня запроса выполняется легко! А у Вас я даже не знаю чем вы выполняете запросы

Comment: Видимо, потому что phpMyAdmin парсит строки запроса и выполняет их в отдельных транзакциях

Comment: @Виктор в заголовке написал же `prepareStatement`

Comment: @carapuz спасибо.

Comment: В phpMyAdmin всё работает потому, что там используется другой коннектор к БД. Который умеет...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по сообщению, используемый коннектор не умеет выполнять мультизапросы (несколько запросов в одной строке).

Все запросы у Вас совершенно однотипны - так что соберите их все в один. Для приведённого запроса это будет

```
DELETE FROM `doctor_1_4` WHERE `date` = '2016-12-1' AND `time` IN ('10:10:00','10:20:00','10:30:00','10:40:00','10:50:00','11:10:00','11:20:00','11:30:00','11:40:00','11:50:00','12:10:00','12:20:00','12:30:00','12:40:00','12:50:00','13:10:00','13:20:00','13:30:00','13:40:00','13:50:00','14:10:00','14:20:00','14:30:00','14:40:00','14:50:00','15:10:00');
```

Comment: бонусом при  таком запросе работать все будет быстрее

Comment: Мне кажется конструкция `in` будет работать гораздо дольше нежели `... and (time=date1 or time=date2...)`, в зависимости от данных конечно

Comment: Конструкция IN будет заведомо НЕ медленнее пачки OR-ов.

Comment: Тут вообще есть некоторая вероятность, что вместо `IN` для целей автора можно использовать `BETWEEN`. Но для этого, конечно, надо знать логику, по которой формируются эти его условия (может, там банально выбирается в интерфейсе начальное и конечное время)

Comment: Судя по данным, он оставляет данные ежечасные и удаляет десятиминутные. Так что кроме BETWEEN потребуется ещё условие, что количество минут ненулевое. Дополнительное условие - ерунда, а вот использование функции во WHERE не даст работать индексу.

Comment: @Akina А вот не факт. Может, там каждый час десятиминутное проветривание (медицина же, судя по `doctor...`), и на это время в принципе записей нет. Но я ж говорю, тут уже надо ориентироваться на специфику задачи.

Comment: @Yaant  Я записываю туда время от, допустим, 10 до 14 с интервалом в 10 минут. Потом на это время может записаться пациент.

Comment: @Tsyklop А, то есть как и подозревалось, банально интервал. А почему пропускаете времена 11:00:00, 12:00:00 и т.д.? Ну и заодно уж скажу: если еще не слишком поздно — пересмотрите архитектуру базы. Отдельная таблица для каждого врача — это очень плохая идея.

Comment: @Yaant те в ручную удалял. они там есть. 

Может есть предложения? долго думал как сделать. ничего лучше не приходит.